# Generating random samples from fit PDF in SciPy (Python)

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

Given a fit distribution to a dataset using scipy.stats with something similar to:

```
data = fetch_data(file)
x = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)

param = scipy.stats.norm.fit(data)
fit_pdf = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, param[0], param[1])
```

What is the best way to generate N=1000 random samples from this fit data? Is it possible to generate random samples given any array of values in a PDF?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to generate the random samples is:

```py
data = fetch_data(file)
x = np.linspace(0, 100, 1000)

param = scipy.stats.norm.fit(data)
random_samples = scipy.stats.norm.rvs(param[0], param[1], size=1000)
```

To generate random samples using a given pdf as an array you can use the following:

```py
fit_pdf = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(x, param[0], param[1])

samples = np.random.choice(x, size=1000, p=fit_pdf/np.sum(fit_pdf))
```

Comment: That makes sense, I will give that a try. Is there a way to do it with the array generated by the pdf method?

Comment: I just updated my answer. Note that this will only generate the x values for which the pdf is defined. Is that enough?